# Problem when applying SpVoice for text-to-speech in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text-to-speech

After I subscribed the event voice.EndStream, the voice.Speak() didn't work and I can't hear anything. How can I fix it?

```
    private IEnumerator StopAudioAndSendData()
    {
        if (realTime > 5)
        {
            currentName = PrintRecordData();
            byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(currentName);
            //SendMicPhoneData(content, Path.GetFileName(currentName));
            ShowInfoLog("hahaha" + content);

            //CurAudioSource.mute = false;
            //CurAudioSource.Play();

            //yield return new WaitUntil(() => !CurAudioSource.isPlaying);

            //CurAudioSource.clip = null;
        }

        CleanTime();
        // Task asyncTask = InvokePython(pyScriptPath, pythonPath, appPath);
        // while (!asyncTask.IsCompleted)
        // {
        //     yield return null;
        // }

        yield return StartCoroutine(AsyncInvokePython(pyScriptPath, pythonPath, appPath));
        LoadString();
        yield return StartCoroutine(AsyncSpeak(comment));
        //XunFeiAPIWebSocket.XunFeiAPI.Play();
        //StartCoroutine(speak(comment));
        //yield return StartCoroutine(AsyncSpeak(comment));
        // yield return null;
        // 如果在问答模式，继续录音
        if (isAsking)
        {
            realTime = 0;
            isRecording = true;
        }
        ShowInfoLog("检测");
    }
```

Below is the speak method, with an async callback.

```
 private IEnumerator AsyncSpeak(string text)
    {
        Task invokeTask = Task.Run(() => SpeakAndWait(text));
        // 等待 InvokePython 方法执行完毕
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => invokeTask.IsCompleted);
    }

    private async Task<bool> SpeakAndWait(string text)
    {
        // 实例化spvoice 对象
        voice = new SpVoice();
        // Item(0)中文语音 Item(1)英文语音 
        voice.Voice = voice.GetVoices(string.Empty, string.Empty).Item(0);
        // 语音速度 范围-10 到10  默认是0
        voice.Rate = 0;
        // 语音音量 范围0到100   默认 100 
        voice.Volume = 100;
        ShowInfoLog("over");
        // 创建一个TaskCompletionSource用于异步等待语音播放完成
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs2 = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        // 注册语音播放完成的回调函数
        voice.EndStream += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // 将异步操作标记为已完成
            tcs2.SetResult(true);
        };

        // 开始语音播放
        voice.Speak(text, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync);

        // 等待语音播放完成
        await tcs2.Task;

        voice.EndStream -= (sender, args) => { };
        // 清除回调函数，避免内存泄漏
        return tcs2.Task.Result;
    }
```

I want the method StopAudioAndSendData() wait for the finish of speaking and then execute the following instructions without blocking the main process.